# Cannot access form field using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following form in my Angular application:

```
<form id="form1">
    <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="frm.myID" />
       <input type="button" name="btnProcess" class="action-button" value="Process" ng-click="Process()" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

In my controller I have:

```
var frm = this;

$scope.Process = function() {
   console.log(frm.myID);

}
```

`frm.myID` comes up as undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: please provide the **entire** controller definition and HTML block, including where `ng-controller` is declared.

Comment: this works correctly, with the limited information you provided, as long as one fills in the blanks and makes some assumptions about the rest of the missing code: http://plnkr.co/edit/71Y2Tzj0hgmWg49g1vH6?p=preview.  Something you haven't posted in the question body is not configured properly, and the rest of the code is necessary in order to identify the issue.

Comment: as a side note, if you are using `this`, you generally shouldn't be saving values on `$scope`.  and if you are using `$scope`, then the `var frm = this` is unnecessary.  Using both syntaxes at the same time only leads to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the object defined on the $scope. Check the below code snippets.

Inside your controller, you seem to be mixing the coding styles i.e. $scope syntax vs. controller aliasing syntax, please go with one approach.

Also please initialize your object to an empty Object i.e. `$scope.frm = {};`

$scope syntax.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

DefaultController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function DefaultController($scope) {
  $scope.frm = {};

  $scope.Process = function() {
    console.log($scope.frm.myID);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <form id="form1">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="frm.myID" />
        <input type="button" name="btnProcess" class="action-button" value="Process" ng-click="Process()" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller aliasing syntax. You can use $scope in this syntax too but for doing things like setting up watchers, events, etc.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.frm = {};
  vm.process = process;

  function process() {
    console.log(vm.frm.myID);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <form id="form1">
      <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="ctrl.frm.myID" />
        <input type="button" name="btnProcess" class="action-button" value="Process" ng-click="ctrl.process()" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still get `$scope.frm.myID` as undefined... Could it be because the page is a partial page, loaded withing another page?

Comment: Seems to me that you are using controller as syntax, Could you please try as the e.g. code snippet I've given with controller aliasing syntax, initially it will print undefined just type some text and click Process button and check

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning controller function to `frm` variable in controller code, so the correct console.log should be `console.log(frm.frm.myId)`. Of course, if you're not using `controller as` syntax.

**Update.**
You probably don't need to frm to this. So try to delete this `var frm = this`. And it will work with console.log `console.log($scope.frm.id)`

Comment: that would only be true if `frm == $scope`, which isn't demonstrated here either.

Comment: Yes, good point. I guess then just there is no need in `var frm = this`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
myapp= angular.module("app",[])
       myapp.controller("yourControllerName",function($scope){
    var frm = this;
    this.myID = ""; // ur missing
    this.Process = function() {
      
       console.log(frm.myID);

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="yourControllerName as frm">
<form id="form1">
    <fieldset>
       <input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="frm.myID" />
     
       <input type="button" name="btnProcess" class="action-button" value="Process" ng-click="frm.Process()" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: I added `frm.myID="";` before my function and I already had my controller with `as` syntax in my config file, but now `console.log(frm.myID);
` comes up as blank